# How to import CSV file with mixed data, including string Mathematica expressions and numbers

Tags: import, date-and-time, csv-format

I am importing a [`CSV`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) file that looks like this (Extract of data as viewed in Notepad):

```
"DateObject[{2022, 4, 11, 7, 0, 0.}, ""Instant"", ""Gregorian"", 1.]",-12.27727296
"DateObject[{2022, 4, 11, 7, 1, 0.}, ""Instant"", ""Gregorian"", 1.]",-12.40909108
"DateObject[{2022, 4, 11, 7, 2, 0.}, ""Instant"", ""Gregorian"", 1.]",-12.40909113
```

**I want to plot this data using [`DateListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html), but as it is it doesn't seem to know how to understand the date-time coordinate values.**

I get the following error:

> DateListPlot::dtvals: Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the given data and DataRange.

---

Just a clarification that this is what the data file looks like when viewed in Excel:

[image]

Comment: I get the following error:  DateListPlot::dtvals: Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the given data and DataRange.

Comment: Thi is what the data looks like in Notepad:"DateObject[{2022, 4, 11, 7, 0, 0.}, ""Instant"", ""Gregorian"", 1.]",-12.27727296
"DateObject[{2022, 4, 11, 7, 1, 0.}, ""Instant"", ""Gregorian"", 1.]",-12.40909108
"DateObject[{2022, 4, 11, 7, 2, 0.}, ""Instant"", ""Gregorian"", 1.]",-12.40909113

Comment: @rhermans yes that works!  I've been banging my head on my desk all afternoon over this

Comment: Ok, let's learn from the experience. This was unnecessarily complicated because you didn't share all the necessary information from the beginning. Next time, please take some time to prepare all the information we can need and present it in a way that is easy for us to read. I have edited your question to a more desirable format.

Comment: Let's delete the comments that are now obsolete so the question can be useful to other people in the future. Also, @Richard, please follow the [tour], you will get a new badge and learn more about how to participate better on this site.

Answer (score 4):

You have a String representation of a Mathematica expression,  you can transform it using [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html). To apply this only to the relevant column you can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) like this

```
DateListPlot@MapAt[ToExpression,  Import[filepath,"CSV"],{All,1}]
```

Other solutions exist, I will leave it for other members of the community to add better alternatives.

[image]